# Twitter API hide results

Tags: php, twitter

I'm calling this example request from within some PHP code on a web page:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi
```

I get the Json result back which is great - but it is always printed within the web page so my users can see it.  How do I do the request but prevent it from outputting to the page?

```
    $curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Thanks

Comment: We need to see your PHP code. Clearly you are outputting JSON when you should be parsing or doing something else with it

Comment: I'm not outputting in PHP.  If you copy and paste that request into your web browser address bar and run it you'll see the result in the browser

Comment: yes, I see. But if you are directing your users to that API call, that's what they'll get in their browsers. If you need the data, you must request it via a PHP call using CURL or `file_get_contents()`, and process it in PHP, not direct your users to it.

Comment: @Simon: the code you added doesn't output anything

Comment: That's not the code you are actually using - the code above will result in a syntax error. Give the code you are actually using, if you actually want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have also fixed the missing closing quote in your URL...

You are using the wrong variable to point to the curl handler in your second `curl_setopt()` call, and therefore not setting the return transfer option correctly:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// Should be
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```